# Would lose skin tighten in the same amount of time it takes to lose weight the slow way?

Tags: weight-loss

Ok so if you lose a lot of weight very quickly and not focus on gaining muscle you will absolutely get loose skin. But it tightens back up anyway especially if you do gain muscle. I was thinking if you let yourself get loose skin wouldn't it just tighten back up in the same time that it takes to lose weight slowly and gradually?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because loose skin is primarily an appearance concern, not a fitness concern.